Troubleshooting Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with Solid PWR and ACT LEDs
I have two Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 units. The first unit, which I will refer to as the "working" one, has a flickering GREEN ACT LED (but no lit RED PWR LED), indicating that it operates normally. In contrast, the "faulty" unit has a solid RED PWR LED and a solid GREEN ACT LED, suggesting it is not functioning as expected. I have tested both units with the exact same SD card, OS image, and power adapter, and while the working unit operates perfectly, the faulty one does not respond at all.
Additionally, the faulty unit has bent GPIO pins, but they don’t appear to be touching each other.
Given that the flickering GREEN ACT LED usually indicates SD card activity, I suspect there’s an issue with the first unit.
What steps can I take to troubleshoot this issue and potentially get the faulty Raspberry Pi working again?


the "faulty" unit has a solid RED PWR LED and a solid GREEN ACT LED

Pretty sure a Pi 2 will do the exact same thing with no SD card in (try it).
If the "faulty" unit won't do anything with an SD card that works in another Pi 2, the SD card reader or some other bit of critical hardware is probably defunct, unfortunately -- it really is faulty, and trying to repair a Pi with this kind of problem is not worthwhile.

Yes, the lights on the "faulty" unit behave exactly the same (solid RED PWR LED and a solid GREEN ACT LED) whether it has the SD Card plugged in or not.

So, it is as good as trash? There is nothing I can do about it?

It eventually happened to me with both my original model B's.  I don't know for sure what was wrong with them except it was pretty clear they never accessed the SD card and never got past starting the GPU (probably if you plug in a display you will just see the big 4-tone "rainbow" screen it draws); the SoCs only got lukewarm.  Exactly why I don't know, but unless you have some really special skills diagnosing it further on the chance that you might be able to replace some bit (more special skills), there's not much to do (and paying someone with such skills will not be worthwhile).
